# how to troubleshoot: why I can't obtain a lock?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In a debugger I "froze" when executing such line of code: `lock (myvar)` Obviously someone else is holding `myvar`. However I expect at this line that `myvar` should be free. So I want to know which part of code holdes `myvar` (from another thread diffenetely). How can I do that? I know which thread holdes it (because I have only one another thread) but I don't know where.

**upd** solved, I forgot to call `Monitor.Exit(myvar)` after one `Monitor.TryEnter(myvar)`

Comment: Just how many lock statements does your code have??

Comment: @AndrewBarber I have only ONE another lock statement and I don't understand how it can keep lock. So I want to make sure in debugger that problem is there.... I've decided to add Console.Writeln("get lock") and Console.Writeln("release lock") tracing...

Comment: Those `Console.Writeline()`s are pretty expensive and could change the timing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know, but this is at least something I can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lock()` statement uses the `Monitor` class which does not support querying the locking threads.
In Fx 4.5 you can check `Monitor.IsEntered(myVar)` but that's about it.

The rest should come from your code's logic.

Comment: There is a `Monitor.IsEntered` method?

Comment: @Jon Only if you use .NET 4.5.

Comment: @Jon - only in the latest version. Edited.

Comment: So this means that I do not have other methods than looking at my code? And if i don't see a problem I should better look at my code? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Visual Studio 2010` you can look on [Parallel Stacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998398.aspx)

Comment: how using it I can find threads or places that "lock" my variable?

Comment: You can see which threads are running *now* can reduce/localize the search... The same as `Monitor.IsEntered` it only informs you that the  `Monitor` already locked, but by whom is another question...